# Postgres sql select result based on a ranking derived from a text column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Scratching my head here. I have a very simple postgres table from which I need to select a unique row per day, based solely on a text column which updates as follows.

First update= 'AA1', 2nd update=  'AB', 3rd update= 'D4'

```
    id  item      date         run    value
    ---------------------------------------
    23  apple     01/01/16      AA1    232
    25  apple     01/01/16      AB     254
    26  apple     01/01/16      D4     212
```

Depending on the time of day, running a query based on the date ('01/01/2016') would return 1, 2 or 3 rows. However I only need the latest row e.g. Run = D4 above.

How can I write a simple select query that always returns just the latest row based of a text based column? I presume i need to create a ranking based on the 'run' column but Im not sure how to do this.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the handy [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
select distinct on (date) *
from t
order by date, run desc
```

Comment: Great work, such a simple solution. Works perfectly. Thanks again.